# Scraping XMR using Python

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape this page: https://store.steampowered.com/search/results/?query&start=0&count=50&dynamic_data=&sort_by=_ASC&snr=1_7_7_7000_7&filter=topsellers&infinite=1

I tried using beautiful soup but it says: TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'
This error occurs on the parsing line. I can't use the regular page for beautiful soup since the function to scrape everything takes way too long. I need to get the info for each item such as the games title, release date, discount, price, and URL through this page.

Here is my code

```
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)
    browser.get("https://store.steampowered.com/search/results/?query&start=0&count=50&dynamic_data=&sort_by=_ASC&snr=1_7_7_7000_7&filter=topsellers&infinite=1")
    url = browser.current_url
    page = requests.get(url)
    data = page.json()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use `selenium` (Too slow).

The steps are easy: Parse the json, and convert `results_html` to soup:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://store.steampowered.com/search/results/?query&start=0&count=50&dynamic_data=&sort_by=_ASC&snr=1_7_7_7000_7&filter=topsellers&infinite=1'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.json()['results_html'], "html.parser")
for game_info in soup.find_all(class_="search_result_row ds_collapse_flag"): # iterate this
    print("url: ",game_info.get("href"))
    print("name: ", game_info.find(class_="title").text.strip())
    print("Released: ", game_info.find(class_="search_released").text.strip())
    for price in game_info.find(class_="search_price"): # filter origin price.
        if price and price.name != 'span': # just check the tag.
            real_price = price
    print("Price: ", real_price.strip())
    discount = game_info.find(class_="search_discount").text.strip()
    if discount: # check whether discount exists
        print("Discount: ", discount)
    else:
        print("No discount")
    print()
```

Print:

```
url:  https://store.steampowered.com/app/1091500/Cyberpunk_2077/?snr=1_7_7_7000_150_1
name:  Cyberpunk 2077
Released:  9 Dec, 2020
Price:  ¥ 298
No discount

url:  https://store.steampowered.com/app/578080/PLAYERUNKNOWNS_BATTLEGROUNDS/?snr=1_7_7_7000_150_1
name:  PLAYERUNKNOWN'S BATTLEGROUNDS
Released:  21 Dec, 2017
Price:  ¥ 98
No discount

url:  https://store.steampowered.com/app/431960/Wallpaper_Engine/?snr=1_7_7_7000_150_1
name:  Wallpaper Engine
Released:  16 Nov, 2018
Price:  ¥ 19
No discount

url:  https://store.steampowered.com/app/1404210/Red_Dead_Online/?snr=1_7_7_7000_150_1
name:  Red Dead Online
Released:  4 Dec, 2020
Price:  ¥ 35
No discount

url:  https://store.steampowered.com/app/1406990/NEKOPARA_Vol_4/?snr=1_7_7_7000_150_1
name:  NEKOPARA Vol. 4
Released:  26 Nov, 2020
Price:  ¥ 33
Discount:  -11%
.....
```